# Prevent Chrome on Android from Popping up Search Overlay

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome, gesture

I'm working on a browser-based music app which has an onscreen keyboard. When I test the keyboard on my android phone in chrome browser it keeps randomly popping up some kind of search overlay. It doesn't do it consistently. It doesn't seem to be tied to long or short taps. It probably only happens about once every 20+ taps. I haven't been able to figure out any pattern or gesture to predict when it's going to happen yet.

I'm not even sure where it's getting its search terms from as the keyboard does not contain text. Sometimes the terms seem to match some of my css class names. For example it once searched for "notation" which is a class name used in the notation area of my app, but not on the keyboard where I was tapping.

I have set the CSS for my keyboard to `user-select: none` but that did not resolve the issue.

I'm not sure if this is a feature in chrome on android, or if it is specific to my device, but I definitely don't want random searches popping up for my users and I'm hoping there is a way I can prevent this from the app itself and not some device settings.

Is anyone familiar with this search "feature" and how to stop it from "helping"?

Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Doh, it's only once I saw my own screenshot enlarged in this question that I noticed some text from the header is getting highlighted. I must be fat-fingering the upper edge of the phone when holding it. I just need to disable user-select on the header too. Thanks anyway!